# Types for arrow function with axios query inside

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

my particular question is about typescript types. I've been searching web but found nothing for that example. What type can I define for a piece of code like this?

```
const useUserApi = () => {
const {
    token,
} = useUserState();

if (!token) return;

const getUserInfo = async () => {
    const res = await axios({
        url: Config.apiUrl + `getter/candidate`,
        method: 'get',
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });

    return res;
}

return {
    getUserInfo,
}
```

}

and I invoke it as

```
const {
    getUserInfo,
} = useUserApi();

useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo()
    .then(function (response:any) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setUserData(prevState => ({ data: response.data, isLoading: false }))
        }
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
        setError(err.response.data.message);
        if(err.response.data.error === 'invalid_token') toggleToken(null)
    });
}, [])
```

IDE says

> const getUserInfo: any
> Property 'getUserInfo' does not exist on type '{ getUserInfo: () => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>; changeUserInfo: (structure: Structure) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>; } | undefined'

Kind thanks for answer

Comment: Are you sure it's how you define it and not how you (attempt to) use it?

Comment: @kellys well yes, I destructurize it from FC and invoke it getUserInfo(). It works fine on classic js file

Comment: you need to provide a fully reproducible example... otherwise we are all guessing

Comment: You return `undefined` if there is no token. TypeScript is asking you to handle the case where there is no token, because if there is no token you will get runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can first write an interface about what you get from the api.

For example if you return array of Users

```
 interface User {
     id: number;
     firstName: string;
 }
```

Then;

```js
 const getUserInfo = async (): Promise<User[]> => { //Array of Users in this case
    const res = await axios({
        url: Config.apiUrl + `getter/candidate`,
        method: 'get',
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
interface ExampleType {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const url = Config.apiUrl + `getter/candidate`
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};

const getUserInfo = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get<ExampleType>( url, config ); 

    return res.data; // The type of res.data is ExampleType
}
```

Tips:

No need to specify the return type of getUserInfo like this:

```
const getUserInfo = async (): Promise<ExampleType> => {}
```

Typescript will infer the type for you.

Comment: Argument of type '{ url: string; config: { headers: { Authorization: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: It was a typepo in the original answer, I removed the addtional brackets in `axios.get<ExampleType>( url, config )`, try it out